# NSFetchedResultController not getting updated

Tags: core-data, restkit, uicollectionview, restkit-0.20, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I am using a `UICollectionView` to manage a to-do list with a `NSFetchedResultController` and RestKit. When I am creating/updating an element with the `postObject:/putObject:` methods, `NSFetchedResultController` does not get updated. If I call the reload method on the collection view new objects are not present. The only solution I found is reloading all the objects with `getObjectsAtPath`.

New objects are well added to the backend storage as well as in the local SQLite database. I set up the `NSFetchedResultController`'s delegate correctly and initialized it with the `mainQueueManagedObjectContext`.

Comment: are you using `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate`? The fetchedResultsController will only update the object it holds when you implement all of the delegate methods.

Comment: Yes I am using it and implementing the different methods associated.

Comment: Are you using cache in NSFechedResultController /